# GNOME Shell showing black on some windows

Tags: gnome

I installed GNOME 13.10.04 today and everything it's ok but there are black areas popping out inside the windows.

I can't take a screenshot because it appears without those black areas in them.

Anybody knows something about this issue?

Comment: What type of graphics card does your computer have?

Comment: Intel HD graphics 4000. They were working OK before gnome installation